# Браузер не выводит данные отправленные методом POST

Tags: php, html, post

Всем привет мужики! Случилась проблема с **POST**:
есть файл **test.php** -

```
<form action="test2.php" method="post" >
    Ваше имя:<input id="login" type="text" name="login"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

И есть файл-обработчик **test2.php** -

```
echo 'Привет, '.$_POST['login'];
```

Файл **test.php** отправляет данные (логин) в обработчик **test2.php**, но браузер выводит просто слово "Привет" и все. Также проверял **var_dump**-ом и выводит **NULL**.
Самое интересное что в инструментах разработчика браузера **Network** в пункте  **Form Data** показаны мои введенные и отправленные данные (логин).
 То есть браузер просто не выводит post данные на экран, хотя в заголовках браузера они есть. Думал может что то с OpenServer, переустановил его, та же фигня! Может кто то уже сталкивался с таким?

Comment: после сабмита у тебя точно нет редиректов каких то ? после echo поставь exit(); что то меняется?

Comment: редиректов нету только закрывающие тэги body и html. Поставил exit() и ничего не поменялось(

Comment: Возможно проблема с браузером? пробовал на других браузерах?

Comment: Да, уже на разных пробовал, то же самое. Есть подозрение что работает сервер PhpStorma а не OpenServer. Не знаю туда я вообще смотрю,но в Network браузера Respons Headers в нем server:PhpStorm 2016.1. То есть я так понимаю сервером является именно PhpStorm, или я не то совсем смотрю.

Comment: @Max1111, Вы уверены что Вы редактируете то, что надо?

Comment: @Max1111, насколько я понимаю то что Вы редактируете никак не связано с тем куда вы отправляете запросы

Comment: @Max1111,  попробуйте идентифицировать test2.php...замените `echo 'Привет, '.$_POST['login'];` на `echo 'Hello, '.$_POST['login'];`...После сохраните и отправьте форму...если надпись будет "Привет", значит Вы чего-то ни того редактируете.

Comment: Выводит только Hello,

Comment: @Max1111 что касается "сервер PhpStorma" я впервые слышу такое... phpStorm - насколько мне известно это редактор, влиять на работу сервера он не может, то что вы в примере дали, я у себя поставил на локальном сервере- всё нормально отправляет. Вы проверили у вас локальный сервер точно включён? Мне кажется у вас сервер не включён )) в test.php поставьте    phpinfo();   что показывает?

Comment: @Max1111, в test2.php напишите пожалуйста следующее: `var_dump($_REQUEST);` и `var_dump($_SERVER);`

Comment: @Max1111, подобное поведение у меня было только когда перед обработкой запроса был считан поток ввода php `file_get_contents('php://input');`

Comment: Мужики, всем спасибо! Случилась эврика) Знаете в шторме, вверху справа, есть такие классные значки браузеров?) ну так вот, при нажатии на любой из них открывалась страничка с адресом **http://localhost:63342/NewsPage/www/test.php**,а данная страница как раз работала под руководством встроенного веб-сервера шторма, а он в свою очередь как то мешал выводу post запросов в браузер. В итоге был прописан вручную в адресной строке http://NewsPage/test.php , и с него замечательно ушли и пришли на http://NewsPage/test2.php данные(в данном случае скрипт обрабатывался уже OpenServerom)вот такая петрушка)

Comment: @Max1111, Вы можете сами оформить ответ и отметить его верным. Он может кому-нибудь пригодиться

Answer (score 1):

В WebStorm вверху справа, есть такие классные значки браузеров. При нажатии на любой из них открывалась страничка с адресом `localhost:63342/NewsPage/www/test.php`, а данная страница как раз работала под руководством встроенного веб-сервера **шторма**, а он в свою очередь как-то мешал выводу post запросов в браузер. В итоге был прописан вручную в адресной строке `NewsPage/test.php` , и с него замечательно ушли и пришли на `NewsPage/test2.php` данные (в данном случае скрипт обрабатывался уже OpenServer'ом).

Comment: Для выделения любого текста, который обрабатывается компьютером, уместно использовать форматирование внутристрочным кодом:  `\`текст\``.