# Переменные из GET/POST массивов не выводятся в браузер (Open Server)

Tags: php, openserver, xmlhttprequest, vbscript

Всем привет!
Такая проблема:
Есть скрипт на VBS, который запускается из приложения WinCCRuntime (такое ПО от Siemens). Скрипт создаёт объект MSXML2.XMLHTTP и отправляет данные обработчику, написанному на PHP, который запускается под OpenServer 5.3.0.Premium на этом же хосте (всё это на виртуальной машине). 
После выполнения скрипта в приложение возвращается readystate "4" и responsetext с соответствующими данными (PHP просто выводит то, что ему прислали). Но на страницу в браузер эти данные не выводятся!!! (Echo вообще ничего не выводит, print_r выводит пустой Array). Проблема одинаковая при использовании GET и POST.
Мне нужно вывести данные в web-приложение. 
В чём может быть проблема?
Смотрела вопрос [Браузер не выводит данные отправленные методом POST](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/616855/%D0%91%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC-post) 
но там был еще один вэб-сервер. У меня просто OpenServer.
Заранее спасибо.
Это код VBS:

```
Sub OnLButtonDown(ByVal Item, ByVal Flags, ByVal x, ByVal y)                                                 


Dim data2
data2=HMIRuntime.Tags("Plant1/RMT1/LI111/CFC_LI111/LIA.#comment").Read


Dim xmlhttp
Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

data1="hello"
xmlhttp.open "GET", "http://localhost:90/ajax1/handler.php?value="&data1, True
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", " *"
xmlhttp.send ""

Dim obj4 
Set obj4 = HMIRuntime.Screens("http").ScreenItems("Button2")
obj4.Text=xmlhttp.readyState

Dim obj3 
Set obj3 = HMIRuntime.Screens("http").ScreenItems("Button3")
obj3.Text=xmlhttp.responseText


End Sub
```

Это код PHP:

```
<?php


    $value=$_GET['value'];

    echo $value."<br/>";


?>
```

[image: 4 - это readystate, hello<br/>- это responsetext]

Comment: а если без скриптов, VBS и приложений, *просто* перейти по ссылке http://localhost:90/ajax1/handler.php?value=value то выводит что-нибудь? Если нет, то инадо все лишнее из вопроса убрать, и задаватьего на форму поддержки OpenServer 5.3.0.Premium. Если выводит, то все лишнее из вопроса убрать, и спрашивать там, где задают вопросы про VBS

Comment: Да, просто по ссылке всё выводится. Но если проблема внутри VBскрипта, то как тогда в приложение возвращается корректный ответ из браузера?

Comment: Я одного не могу понять в этом путанном объяснении: при чем здесь  Echo и print_r? В какой момент они выоплняются? Почему они вообще здесь упоминаются,если перед этим пишется, что " После выполнения скрипта в приложение возвращается readystate "4" и responsetext с соответствующими данными (PHP просто выводит то, что ему прислали)."? РНР уже вывел данные. Откуда здесь дополнительные Echo и print_r? В какой браузер они должны что-то выводить? Какие данные? откуда?

Comment: Открываю хромом файл handler.php. Если просто в адресной строке передать данные , они выводятся на странице. Если запрос приходит из стороннего приложения, то в приложение респонс возвращается, а на странице данные не выводятся.

Comment: с какой стати данные должны выводиться на странице, если запросила их не страница, а приложение?

Comment: Да, правильно вы спросили. php-скрипт вызывается из vbs-скрипта и нормально отрабатывает. А так, чтобы данные еще и странице выводились без перезагрузки, нужно использовать js

Answer (score -1):

```
DataToSend = "value="&data1

xmlhttp.send DataToSend
```

Comment: Сергей, данные в send передаются, если используется POST, а в GET они должны быть в Open. Но так или иначе, в браузере PHP их не выводит, хотя они попадают в $_GET

Comment: а если POST отправить?

Comment: и еще  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", " *" - почему пробел перед *

Comment: POST тот же результат, пробелы тут тоже никак не влияют